# How to extract the beginning and end date from a text file with a specific keyword with python

Tags: python, date, extract

This is an example text:

```
Jan 1 11:22:33 DHCPDISCOVER from 00:11:22:33:44:55
Jan 1 11:22:34 DHCPOFFER on 10.0.0.5 to 00:11:22:33:44:55
Jan 1 11:22:35 DHCPREQUEST for 10.0.0.5 from 00:11:22:33:44:55
Jan 1 11:22:36 DHCPACK on 10.0.0.5 to 00:11:22:33:44:55
Jan 1 11:22:37 DHCPNACK on 10.0.0.5 to 00:11:22:33:44:55
```

I want to extract for the specific mac address when it was first registered with a date and time and the last time it was registered.

The output has to be something like this:

```
for the given mac address: 00:11:22:33:44:55
Start: Jan 1 11:22:33
End: Jan 2 22:33:44
```

Comment: please share with us what you tried? Else we'll think that you want us to do your home-work

Comment: Your timestamp doesn't include a year? That's odd.

Comment: Use `re.match` to parse each line, `time.strptime` to convert the timestamp portion to a datetime, MAC address as a dict key, and keep the max/min datetime for each dict entry. Should take about four minutes including testing.

Comment: Sorry for not posting anything yet @ Moinuddin. I did not have any idea how to do it yet. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @Hugh. Now I can use the re.findall.
So I think I can find it with this to begin with:  date= re.findall ('\w{3}\b\d{1}\b\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', line)

Something like that, not tested it out. Just thinking out loud here.

Comment: @HughBothwell I triend it without converting it into pyhton format with tuples. Can you maybe give me some insight why this is not working:
`date= re.findall (r'\w{3}\s\d{1,2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', line)`
 `date_t=tuple(date)`
 `start=min(date_t)`
 `end=max(date_t)`

Comment: ... that matches an entire date-string, ie "Jan 1 11:22:33". Try using `r'(\w{3})\s(\d{1,2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})'` instead.

Comment: I get this error without the line command: TypeError: findall() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'

Comment: I am getting the same start and end date, something is going wrong with my tuple it think

for the given mac address: 00:11:22:33:44:55
Start: Jan 1 11:22:33
End: Jan 1 11:22:33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#read file
file = open ("test.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

#nullpoint
DHCPDISCOVER = 0
DHCPOFFER= 0
DHCPREQUEST= 0
DHCOPACK= 0
DHCPACK= 0
start=0
end=0

#Input MAC from user
mac=str (input("For what MAC address do you want to parse: "))

#Capture date respectively to MAC
import re
y=[]
for line in lines:
    if line.find(mac) !=-1:
        ip = re.findall ('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', line)
        date = re.findall (r'\w{3}\s\d{1,2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', line)
        y.append(date[0])

#find the keywords
for line in lines:
    if line.find ("DHCPDISCOVER") != -1 and line.find(mac) !=-1:
        DHCPDISCOVER=+1
    if line.find ("DHCPOFFER") != -1 and line.find(mac) !=-1:
        DHCPOFFER=+1
    if line.find ("DHCPREQUEST") != -1 and line.find(mac) !=-1:
        DHCPREQUEST=+1
    if line.find ("DHCOPACK") != -1 and line.find(mac) !=-1:
        DHCOPACK=+1
    if line.find ("DHCPACK") != -1 and line.find(mac) !=-1:
        DHCPACK=+1

#display results
print ("Start: ", min(y))
print ("End: ",   max(y))
print ("MAC: ", mac)
print ("DHCPDISCOVER: ",DHCPDISCOVER,"x")
print ("DHCPOFFER:    ",DHCPOFFER,"x")
print ("DHCPREQUEST:  ",DHCPREQUEST,"x")
print ("DHCOPACK:     ",DHCOPACK,"x")
print ("DHCPACK:      ",DHCPACK,"x")
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: I want ... for ... mac ... first registered ... and last ... registered.

You want somethind like this:

```
mac_dict = {}
for line in in_file:
    words = line.split(' ')
    if words[3] == 'DHCPACK':
        mac = words[-1]
        datetime = ' '.join(words[:3])
        if not mac in mac_dict:
            mac_dict[mac] = {'first_date':datetime, 'last_date': None}
        else:
            mac_dict[mac]['last_date'] = datetime

for mac in mac_dict:
    print("for the given mac address: {}\nStart:{m[first_date]}\nEnd:{m[last_date]}".format(mac, m=mac_dict[mac]))
```